# SteamVR No Longer Opening With Unity Projects

Tags: unity, windows, steam-vr

I'm trying to get Unity to open/utilize SteamVR for development. Everything was working fine until today, but now Unity does not use SteamVR.

I did not make any changes to SteamVR recently, and I get the same results on multiple projects and Unity installs. I also tried rebooting.

It looks like Windows pushed an update today for KB4023057 but I can't uninstall it. It's not found within uninstall updates, not in add/remove programs, and even using command prompt wusa /uninstall /kb:4023057 results in "KB4023057 is not installed." So it seems I'm stuck with it.

Any other ideas to either try to uninstall the update or else to somehow get SteamVR working in Unity again?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the code and ran it outside the Unity Editor and it actually connected to VR. Then, after that, it started connecting via the Unity Editor again. Bizarre!